# Does Tomcat provided support for Java 9 BETA

Tags: tomcat, java-9

I am working on Java 9 BETA version using Eclipse Mars , Want yo know does  Tomcat provided support for Java 9 BETA ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Update August 26, 2017***

In my quest to answer [Run Vaadin 8.1 app under Java 9 prerelease in IntelliJ 2017.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766064/run-vaadin-8-1-app-under-java-9-prerelease-in-intellij-2017-2-2/45803963#45803963), I'd discovered that

[Apache-tomcat-9.0.x](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/index.html) is compatible with Java 9 and can be configured to start with

> ```
> Using JRE_HOME:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/
> ```

using a [JDK9 Early Access](http://jdk.java.net/9/) currently in the final candidate stage.

Answer (score 0):

As long as Java 9 is fully compatible with previous versions, Tomcat should run OK.

There may be some smaller issue and Java 9 sets 9 months for testing only. I think most of Java projects will start checking with Java 9 after December 2015, when it will be feature complete. Read more at http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/