# Run Vaadin 8.1 app under Java 9 prerelease in IntelliJ 2017.2.2

Tags: tomcat8, java-9, vaadin8

In IntelliJ 2017.2.2 I am able to run a Vaadin 8.1.2 app (brand-new `vaadin-archetype-application` archetype) with Tomcat 8.5.20 under Java 9+181 if the `Project Structure` > `Project SDK` is set to Java 1.8.

If `Project Structure` > `Project SDK` is set to Java 9 I get this compiler error around `FillIn` with assertion error about `filling` something to do with Vaadin MouseEvents. I have tried googling but found no clues.

```
Information:java: An exception has occurred in the compiler (9). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.fillIn(ClassFinder.java:340)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.complete(ClassFinder.java:285)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:633)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:1314)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.flags(Symbol.java:1248)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.isAccessible(Resolve.java:405)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.isAccessible(Resolve.java:389)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findImmediateMemberType(Resolve.java:2170)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMemberType(Resolve.java:2225)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findIdentInType(Resolve.java:2403)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.selectSym(Attr.java:3588)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3453)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:2104)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:653)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribType(Attr.java:713)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribType(Attr.java:706)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribBase(Attr.java:859)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$AbstractHeaderPhase.attribSuperTypes(TypeEnter.java:669)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$HierarchyPhase.runPhase(TypeEnter.java:742)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$Phase.doCompleteEnvs(TypeEnter.java:270)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$HierarchyPhase.complete(TypeEnter.java:785)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$HierarchyPhase.doCompleteEnvs(TypeEnter.java:730)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$Phase.completeEnvs(TypeEnter.java:245)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter$Phase.completeEnvs(TypeEnter.java:254)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter.complete(TypeEnter.java:195)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.isInterface(Symbol.java:393)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:2353)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:2641)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClassBuffer(ClassReader.java:2706)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClassFile(ClassReader.java:2719)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.fillIn(ClassFinder.java:348)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.complete(Type.java:1139)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.getTypeArguments(Type.java:1065)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.isErroneous(Type.java:1095)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkNonCyclicInternal(Check.java:2316)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkNonCyclicInternal(Check.java:2327)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkNonCyclicInternal(Check.java:2330)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkNonCyclicInternal(Check.java:2323)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkNonCyclic(Check.java:2277)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkBase(Attr.java:901)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribBase(Attr.java:860)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:577)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:554)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:1052)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:923)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:142)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:96)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:90)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:190)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:473)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:328)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:255)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:208)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1260)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:937)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1009)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:900)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:733)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:385)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:192)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:295)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'vnine'
Information:javac 9 was used to compile java sources
Information:Module "vnine" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes
Information:2017-08-18, 15:40 - Compilation completed with 2 errors and 0 warnings in 1s 866ms
Error:java: java.lang.AssertionError: Filling jar:file:///Users/basilbourque/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-server/8.1.2/vaadin-server-8.1.2.jar!/com/vaadin/ui/Component$Event.class during JarFileObject[/Users/basilbourque/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-server/8.1.2/vaadin-server-8.1.2.jar:/com/vaadin/event/MouseEvents$ClickEvent.class]
Error:java:     at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:162)
```

So, two questions:

- Can IntelliJ + Vaadin + Tomcat be made to work under Java 9 yet? (that is, running *as* a Java 9 project – does indeed run *on* Java 9 but only as a Java 8 project)
- If so, what might be the problem in my case using a brand-new unmodified Vaadin application Maven archetype?

Comment: Could you please share the code you're using for trying this out.

Comment: @nullpointer After my own project failed with settings described above, I tried a brand-new project generated from the first Maven archetype [listed here](https://vaadin.com/maven#archetypes). I never touched the Java code, did not even open the Java files.

Comment: Seems like sadly the answer to the question could be *NO* yet. Tried creating a project using Jetty instead of Tomcat. Was able to package war. But neither does the `.war` works in tomcat(getting 404 even after the war is placed in webapps) and on the other hand with jetty ended up with [another issue](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1758)!

Comment: finally a solution to this was found. Have updated the answer.

Comment: See Vaadin blog post: [*More on Java 9 compatibility*](https://vaadin.com/blog/more-on-java-9-compatibility)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Inlined as timeline*

- What might be the problem in my case using a brand-new unmodified Vaadin application Maven archetype?

To get to the root cause for your case specifically, we would surely need more details to what you've tried in terms of code definitions.

- Can IntelliJ + Vaadin + Tomcat be made to work under Java 9 yet?*

**`On 22 August 2017`**

**Yes**.You can make this specific combination work. After solving the problem where I was [Unable to process file module-info.class within a Java9 project results in ClassFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802981/unable-to-process-file-module-info-class-within-a-java9-project-results-in-class?noredirect=1&lq=1) I could get the war created using `mvn package` to run with tomcat finally.

*Details*: You need to use a Java 9 compatible version of Tomcat. (`apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26` in my case) and configure it to start with

*`Using JRE_HOME: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/`*

Once the server is started, you can access the application @ `localhost:8080/vaadinjavanine/` where *vaadinjavanine* is the war file name within my tomcat's webapps folder.

**`On 21 August 2017`**

The answer specific to the combination sadly is still **No**. I believe it's not yet possible to make this combination work.

***Jetty Server***

Here's a [sample application](https://github.com/namannigam/Jigsaw/tree/master/vaadinjdk9) updated by me which ***works with IntelliJ + Vaadin + Jetty***  on my `localhost:8080` using Jetty server, irrespective of my Project SDK being set to Java1.8 or Java9. It works something like this:

[image: Vaadin default application]

This was attained after overcoming the [#jetty.project/1758](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1758) by upgrading to the `6.0_BETA` of `asm` and `asm-commons` libraries and using the custom [`9.4.7-SNAPSHOT`](https://github.com/namannigam/Jigsaw/blob/master/vaadinjdk9/pom.xml#L19) built on my local used in the project(commit - [#e34415](https://github.com/namannigam/jetty.project/commit/e2ed29ff7e46bdee6f4c126e48bfb311d9e34415).)

***Tomcat Server***

1. Following the recommended way of creating a war, I 've created the application war(in my case `<finalName>vaadinjavanine</finalName>`) using the command:

   ```
   mvn package
   ```
2. Made sure that the CATALINA_HOME/webapps included this file. Copied it basically.
3. Started tomcat on the default port to access the url for the application: `localhost:8080/vaadinjavanine/`

But have ended up finding another issue in the current chain:
[Unable to process file module-info.class within a Java9 project results in ClassFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802981/unable-to-process-file-module-info-class-within-a-java9-project-results-in-class)

---

**`On 20 August 2017`**

The answer to the question is **No**.
What I did was, tried out creating a maven based vaadin application from scratch based out of java9, following the [getting started guide](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/getting-started/getting-started-maven.html). Using the following configurations:

> ```
> apache-tomcat-8.0.22 
>
> intelliJ-IDEA 2017.2.2
>
> <vaadin.version>8.1.2</vaadin.version>
>
> Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-04T01:09:06+05:30)
> Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.0/libexec
> Java version: 9, vendor: Oracle Corporation (jdk-9+181)
> ```

Created a maven module using the `vaadin-archetype-application` as shared in the guide shared. Updated

1. pom.xml with

   ```
   <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
   ```
2. Added a [`module-info.java`](https://github.com/namannigam/Jigsaw/blob/master/vaadinjdk9/src/main/java/module-info.java) to the module under development.

I was able to execute `mvn package` on the same but running `mvn jetty:run` to run the application ended up achieving [MultiException | java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning UI and Servlet class](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1758)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and updates. Since Tomcat 9 is not yet recommended, the answer is still "No" for running the mainstream Tomcat 8.5.x. As for your first sentence, my case is not specific at all. I simply ran the initial app created automatically be the Vaadin.com-provided Maven archetype documented in Question. No code of my own at all.

Comment: FYI: See Vaadin blog post: [*More on Java 9 compatibility*](https://vaadin.com/blog/more-on-java-9-compatibility)